# How do I locate a Word application window?

Tags: windows, vb.net, interop, ms-word, ms-office

I have a VB.net test application that clicks a link that opens the Microsoft Word application window and displays the document. How do I locate the Word application window so that I can grab some text from it?

Comment: Exactly the same way you locate any other application window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Word COM object to open the work document and then you manipulate it. Make sure to add a reference for Microsoft Word first.

```
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word

Public Class Form1

Inherits System.Windows.Forms.Form

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

Dim strFileName As String
Dim wordapp As New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application
Dim doc As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document

Try
    doc = wordapp.Documents.Open("c:\testdoc.doc")
    doc.Activate()

Catch ex As COMException

    MessageBox.Show("Error accessing Word document.")

End Try

End Sub

End Class
```

The doc object is a handle for the instance of Word you have created and you can use all the normal options (save, print etc). You can do likewise with the wordapp. A trick is to use the macro editor in Word to record what you want to do. You can then view this in the Macro Editor. This give you a great starting point for your VB code.

Also, be sure to dispose of the Word COM objects at the end.

Answer (score 1):

I've done something similar with a SourceSafe dialog, which I posted on my blog.  Basically, I used either Spy++ or Winspector to find out the window class name, and make Win32 calls to do stuff with the window.  I've put the source on my blog: http://harriyott.com/2006/07/sourcesafe-cant-leave-well-alone.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to [activate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dyz95fhy(VS.80).aspx) the word app? If you want full control, you need to automate word from your vb.net app. Check here for some samples: [1](http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=303294), [2](http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=302816)